# Should I perform Cross Validation first and then do grid search?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am new to the area in Machine Learning. My question is the following: I have built a model, and I am trying to optimize such model. By doing some research I found out that cross-validation could be used to help me avoid having an overfitted model. Moreover, Gridsearchcv could be used to help me optimize the parameters of such model and eventually identify the best possible parameters.

Now my question is should I do cross-validation first and then use grid search to identify the best parameters or using GridsearchCV would be enough given it performs cross-validation itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Noki, You can use the cv parameter in Grid Search CV.

```
GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, scoring=None, n_jobs=None, iid='deprecated', 
refit=True, cv=None, verbose=0, 
pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs',error_score=nan,return_train_score=False)
```

Also the documentation clearly states that if it's a classification problem it will automatically ensure that it is stratified.

> For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or 
>     multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases, KFold is used.

However, there is something that i would like to add:
You can make your K-folds dynamic with respect to your value count of your Y_target variable.
You cannot have the lowest count of your frequency in K-fold as 1, it will throw an error while training. I have happened to face this. Use the below code snippet to help you with that.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
Y_target=pd.Series([0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6])

if Y_target.value_counts().iloc[-1]<2:
    raise Exception ("No value can have frequency count as 1 in Y-target")
else:
    Kfold=Y_target.value_counts().iloc[-1]
```

You can then assign Kfold to your cv parameter in Grid Search

Comment: My problem is a multi-class classification problem so it would be better to use stratified k folds rather than a normal k fold? If so why is this so? As I can't find anything related to it.

Comment: Yes it would be better to use Stratified K-fold since it will ensure that the ratio of data between your train and test set will remain the same.

Comment: If you do that in GridSearch CV, it is automatically taken care of. Use the above code snippet to determine the folds. You take the same value or any value lesser than the value of the variable K-fold. No issues.

Answer (score 3):

See [Cross validation with test data set](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148688/cross-validation-with-test-data-set/148698#148698).

My recommendation, if your dataset is large enough:

1. Split your dataset into training and test subsets.
2. Perform a [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) on your training dataset.
3. Evaluate your best model (from the GridSearchCV) on your test subset.

Comment: Splitting my data into training and testing by using the Cross-Validation would be appropriate rather than using the split for example 80% training and 20% testing?

Comment: If you have enough data, split your dataset before the GridSearchCV into training and test. See for example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148688/cross-validation-with-test-data-set/148698#148698

Comment: Thanks for your information, I will split my data using Cross-validation then, I will train such model on such data and eventually use  GridSearchCV (by specifying the same number of folds) to identify the different parameters which the model could take. Do you think this is a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is should I do cross-validation first and then use grid search to identify the best parameters or using GridsearchCV would be enough given it performs cross-validation itself?

**The second**. GridSearchCV uses cross-validation splitting strategy to select the best parameters. If you read the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), there is a parameter called "cv" and it defines 5-fold cross-validation by default. If you need to use another cross-validation strategy, you can give it an int, cross-validation generator or an iterable

Comment: So there wouldn't be the need to split the data from beforehand given that grid search performs CV as well right?

Comment: Yep, at most, you could do an 80-20 split (or 10 or whichever) if you want to use that 20 as validation data set and be more secure that your model generalizes well.